# Default Caret appearing over top of custom-select carets in Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Even when I download a fresh copy and compile, the issue persists.  If I use the CDN version, it works fine.  Shouldn't the compiled version with zero changes be identical to the CDN version?

[Screenshot of dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWJIR.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one caused me a lot of grief! It looks like the following two lines are missing in _custom_forms.scss and should be placed on line 179:

-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;

Strange that they're there in the CDN version.

Answer (score 0):

**You don't really need to do all that (compile)**

What I do is go to the official bootstrap 4 site, then at top nav bar click on examples, then click download source code. This contains templates you can start with.

Comment: I have a lot of customizations.  I assumed that was what was causing the issue, which is why I tried compiling it without any changes at all on a fresh download, but still had the same issue.  I expected the compiled version without any changes would be identical to the CDN version but it isn't.